# "outline" is not a valid style property

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, radium

I am trying to reuse some components built for web application using [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs)with [radium](/questions/tagged/radium).

I have a component which contains `outline` css property . I reuse the component , unfortunalty , i got this error :

[image]

## My questions are :

- What is the alternative of `outline` property in [react-native](/questions/tagged/react-native) for both [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) or [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) ?
- Is there alternative of [radium](/questions/tagged/radium) in [react-native](/questions/tagged/react-native) ?
- Should I manage manually this difference of style properties naming among iOs DEV, android DEV as well as web DEV ?

Answer (score 1):

use `outlineStyle: "none",`

Comment: outlineStyle does not work for iOS

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023-09-19, it appears that React Native does not provide an equivalent to CSS `outline` or `outlineStyle`. Therefore, giving credit to `@siddharth Alagesan` you can use the following approach:

```js
if (Platform.OS === 'web') outlineStyle = "none"
```

Comment: Even though this solution doesn't result in an error for iOS, OP was looking for an alternative for iOS and/or Android.

Answer (score -4):

I think you are looking for the border styles.

[More specifically from the facebook react native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#style):

```
borderWidth ReactPropTypes.number
borderStyle ReactPropTypes.oneOf(['solid', 'dotted', 'dashed'])
```

So for instance if you wanted to make a 10 x 10 box with dashed lines...

```
<View style={{ borderWidth:1, borderStyle: 'dashed', width: 10, height: 10, }} />
```

Comment: `outline` in CSS is not the same as `border`, because it doesn't affect the outer dimensions, which `border` does.